# How to verify that Amazon Kinesis Python client is working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, consumer, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to build an Amazon Kinesis Python consumer using the KCL library for Python (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-python). I started by checking the sample code. I was able to run both producer and consumer scripts parts of the sample code, but I'm unable to verify if the data from my kinesis stream (with one shard) is being pushed to the sample Python consumer script, `sample_kclpy_app.py`.

I used the `amazon_kclpy_helper.py` to generate the Java command that would call the Python script through the `sample.properties` file. I ran the Java command, and I can see from the terminal output that the data from the Kinesis stream is being read. I added a `print` statement in the `process_record` function of the Python consumer script to check if the data was being pushed to it. But it doesn't show up in the terminal output.

I also tried using `logging` to generate STDOUT messages, as well as write to a file. I also added `assert 0` line in the Python code to force fail the script and see an exception would appear in the log output. Then, I purposely added a syntax error in the Python code. However, it seems that all of these were not detected by the Java MultiLangDaemon, which just kept going and churning out INFO log messages.

What could be the problem?
And is there a better way to check if the data is indeed being sent to the `process_record` function of the Python consumer script?

Comment: it's great this question has been here for 3+ years and AWS won't do a thing to address it. Bozo busy stacking paper I guess, devs too busy crying at their cubes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After numerous trial and error, I figured out that the Python script assigned to `executableName` should be visible from the Java KCL process that is calling it.

The quick fix is to set the `PATH` environmental variable to the directory of the script and make the script an executable file (e.g. `chmod +x`)

Comment: I also had to re-run `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue where my code just seemed to never run.  It wasn't until I looked at the Node version that I realized that `executableName` in `sample.properties` was the command that is run and not just the name of the python file.  I changed `executableName = sample_kclpy_app.py`
 to `executableName = python sample_kclpy_app.py`
 and it started working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did that as well and got it to work. I think the real trick though is that the script should be visible anywhere (i.e. set PATH variable to top directory of the script). I set my PATH to point to the script directory, made the script as executable via `chmod`, and got it to work.